# xcode add a class/object to a subview

Tags: xcode, class, uiview, subview

Hope you can help. I basically need to add an object to a UIView that is within a UIView.

In interface builder I have my View, and inside that I have another View with an image (map) inside (all done with Interface Builder). The second view I am using a class called "MainGameMapViewController" (reason being is that the first view is static/contains text/scores etc. and the view inside that is the game, and this whole view is draggable with the code in "MainGameMapViewController").

I need to add objects to "MainGameMapViewController" UIView.

I have added a class called "CharMain" and used this code inside the **MainViewController**:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    CharMain* charMain = [[CharMain alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 280, 0, 0)];
    [self.view addSubview:charMain];

}
```

CharMain contains the code that draws a rect and adds an image, this works fine, BUT it needs to be added to the second view "MainGameMapViewController".

I have tried adding the code inside the MainGameMapViewController file, and it says "**error: request for member 'view' in something not a structure or union**", I have tried 
    [self addSubview:charMain];

This comes up with no errors, but the image doesnt appear, how do I make this appear within the second UIView? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CharMain* charMain = [[CharMain alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 280, 0, 0)];
//this should be your subview instead of self.view try adding it to your subview's instance.
    [MainGameMapViewControllerInstance.view addSubview:charMain];
```

Comment: Thanks, so do I add this too "MainGameMapViewController" class? I tried adding this to the MainGameViewController, and to "MainGameMapViewController", and it came up with an error for: **MainGameMapViewControllerInstance**. I changed this to ** MainGameMapViewController** and still an error.

Comment: MainGameMapViewController is I assume is subclass of UIViewController. So MainGameMapViewController have it's own view you need to add your charMain to that view.

Comment: Ok ive just solved this with alot of trial and error! Thought id post and let others know.

In the MainGameViewController, I just added the
    IBOutlet UIView *mapView;
into the .h
and linked the second UIView to that outlet.

and in the .m changed the code to:
    [self.**mapView** addSubview:charMain];

Thanks

Comment: if still you are unable to do this send me your code by mail. I'll update it.